# ASP.Net MVC - model with collection, Submit

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a Model that looks like

```
public class Patient
{
    private ICollection<Refill> _refills = new List<Refill>();
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
                  
    public virtual ICollection<Refill> Refills
    {
        get { return _refills; }
        set { _refills = value; }
    }
}

public class Refill
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public RefillActivityStatus RefillActivityStatus { get; set; }
    public DateTime? RefillDate { get; set; }
    public RefillType RefillType { get; set; }
    public string RXNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Here is what I am trying to do. I would like to Populate these in the View and when the user clicks save changes. I would like Entity Framework to save. The problem I am having is in the View I do this

```
@foreach (var m in Model.Refills)
{
     @Html.HiddenFor(model=>m.Id)
     <div class="editor-label">
         @Html.LabelFor(model => m.RXNumber)
     </div>
     <div class="editor-field">
         @Html.EditorFor(model => m.RXNumber)                                  
     </div>     
}
```

I am trying to do in the Controller something like this

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Details(Patient patient)
{
    Patient p = db.Patients.Find(patient.Id);
    db.Entry(p).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.Entry(p).CurrentValues.SetValues(patient);
    // Would include Refill changes too but it doesn't
    db.SaveChanges();

    return View(p);
}
```

However, Refills doesn't propagate on HttpPost. It is just empty, what do I need to do to fix it?

Comment: Could you please show the form code that allows the user to input values?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this insted of your `foreach`:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Refills.Count(); i++)
{
    @Html.Hidden("Refills[" + i + "].Id", Model.Refills[i].Id)
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.Label("Refills[" + i + "].RXNumber", Model.Refills[i].RXNumber)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.Editor("Refills[" + i + "].RXNumber")
    </div>     
}
```

Comment: Im getting The type arguments for method 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.LabelExtensions.LabelFor<TModel,TValue>(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<TModel>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TModel,TValue>>, string)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly. for the LabelFor

Comment: becouse you need to map the value as `Refills[ix].RXNumber` (setting this as the name), with the other way, you are using a helper (`EditorFor`) that creates an input with the name `RXNumber`, which is wrong (must be `Refills[i].RXNumber` to map it correctly)

Comment: Ok, thanks, but I also found that you can still use @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.Refills[i].RXNumber) without having to create the strings manually.