# MVC Model with List<Object>Attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list, razor

I am newish to MVC and am trying to make a registration page that let's users register up to 5 "characters".  I am setting it up so that the region is a drop down list and the character name is a textbox field.  Here is an example of my setup for one character that I got working but I want to allow users to signup multiple and link them all to their account:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("RegisterUser", "Account"))
```

{

```
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { data_bind = "value: Name:", @class = "form-control app-fill-lightgray app-border-darkgray fieldInput", @placeholder = "Username" })
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CharacterName, new { data_bind = "value: Name:", @class = "form-control app-fill-lightgray app-border-darkgray fieldInput", @placeholder = "Charactername" })
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Server, Model.Server, new { data_bind = "value: Name:", @class = "form-control app-fill-lightgray app-border-darkgray fieldInput" })
        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { data_bind = "value: Name:", @class = "form-control app-fill-lightgray app-border-darkgray fieldInput", @placeholder = "Password" })
        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { data_bind = "value: Name:", @class = "form-control app-fill-lightgray app-border-darkgray fieldInput", @placeholder = "Confirm Password" })

        <button type="submit" id="LoginButton" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">Register</button>


    </div>
</fieldset>
```

}

Here is the Register.cs model:

```
 public class Register
{

    public Register()
    {
        this.Servers = new SelectList(
               new List<Object>{
                   new { value = 0 , text = "na"  },
                   new { value = 1 , text = "eu" },
                },
               "value",
               "text",
                0);
    }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Username Required:")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [ValidSummonerAttribute(ErrorMessage="Invalid Summoner Name")]
    //[Required(ErrorMessage = "Character Name Required:")]
    public string CharacterName { get; set; }    

    public int Server { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password Required")]
    [DisplayName("Password:")]
    [RegularExpression(@"(?!^[0-9]*$)(?!^[a-zA-Z]*$)^(.{8,})$", ErrorMessage = "Password must be at least 8 characters and contain one numeric character")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [System.Web.Mvc.Compare("Password", ErrorMessage="Passwords must match")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Confirm Password Required:")]
    [DisplayName("Confirm Password:")]
    [RegularExpression(@"(?!^[0-9]*$)(?!^[a-zA-Z]*$)^(.{8,})$", ErrorMessage = "Password must be at least 8 characters and contain one numeric character")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

}

What I would really like is to setup a Character Info object like this:

```
public class CharacterInfo
{
    int Server { get; set; }
    string CharacterName { get; set; }
}
```

And give the model an attribute of List characters.

I am stuck and can not seem to find a way to do it, any help or examples are much appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14563471/asp-net-mvc-model-with-collection-submit
Is this what you want to achieve?

Comment: It looks really close thanks I'll play with it a bit!

Could you explain

@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Refills.Count(); i++)

Where the Refills.Count() value is set?  I want to set it up so that when I user clicks a button another input field is shown to supply the data for another Character.

Comment: That is worded poorly sorry, what I mean is could you explain how I would go about adding additional "Refills" to the model in Javascript?

Comment: Figured it out using this:
http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/
But you got me 99 percent of the way there so I will mark you as the answer.

EDIT: Guess I can't do that I'm new to this place, thanks for your help!