# Submit the value of each item of list to controller (MVC)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to make some kind of a shopping cart, so I show a list of items in a view.

I added a submit button with the value "+ Add" and a number input with the value amount for each of the items displayed.

This is my code:

VIEW:

```
@model MyProject.ViewModel.AddProductsViewModel

@{
    Layout = null;
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<table class="table" align="left" style="padding-left:15px">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Product
        </th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model.ProductsList)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Descripcion)
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="hidden" name="ProductId" value="@item.ProductId" />                                                                       
                <input type="number" id="Amount" name="Amount"
                       min="1" max="30" value="1">
                <input type="submit" value="+ Add" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
}
```

Model class:

```
public class AddProductsViewModel
{
    ...stuff here...
          
    public List<Products> ProductsList { get; set; }
}
```

I need my controller to get the `productId` from the item I clicked submit to, but this way I'm only getting the Id of the first item of the list. How can I make that happen?

Comment: You need to use an index for the item names (switch your `foreach` to a `for` loop and use the indexer in the `name` attribute of your form fields so that the name attribute is unique to each input)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ASP.Net MVC - model with collection, Submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14563471/asp-net-mvc-model-with-collection-submit)

Comment: I got the same answer in a previous thread about this issue but in that solution I don't get why they give that value to the hidden input @devlincarnate

Answer (score 2):

```
@{int i = 0;}
@foreach (var item in Model.ProductsList)
{

    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Descripcion)
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="hidden" name="ProductsList[@i].ProductId" value="@item.ProductId" />                                                                       
            <input type="number" id="Amount" name="ProductsList[@i].Amount"
                   min="1" max="30" value="1">
            <input type="submit" value="+ Add" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </td>
    </tr>
     @(i++)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just solved the issue by begining the form inside the loop like this:

```
@model MyProject.ViewModel.AddProductsViewModel

@{
    Layout = null;
}


    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<table class="table" align="left" style="padding-left:15px">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Product
        </th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model.ProductsList)
    {
using (Html.BeginForm())
{
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Descripcion)
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="hidden" name="ProductId" value="@item.ProductId" />                                                                       
                <input type="number" id="Amount" name="Amount"
                       min="1" max="30" value="1">
                <input type="submit" value="+ Add" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
}
</table>
```

Comment: This is a hack and doesn't resolve the issue that you have invalid HTML (multiple fields with the same id), and generally isn't the way one would want to post a shopping cart...item by item???

Comment: agree, you'll probably want to use javascript/AJAX to add to card/update the quantity without a full postback

Comment: Any ajax or js guide to aproach that? @GlynnHurrell

Comment: start by searching 'asp net mvc ajax post tutorial' in your search engine of choice